# In firefox, is it possible to use nsIStreamListener in the WebExtensions?

Tags: firefox-addon

Firefox pages tell that XPCOM is not supported anymore, but I want to know if WebExtensions supports or have equivalent of `nsIStreamListener`. Can't live without it.

Also, know of any forum where I can discuss addon development? One question at the time wouldn't be enough.

Also, how to open a new tab, and fill it with html, using XPCOM? I know only about `gBrowser.addTab`, but it requires me to have an empty html file, not very pretty. Wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [webRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) API if it suits your needs regarding `nsIStreamListener`. There's also a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) on how to intercept HTTP requests.

You can always find development tips and information about WebExtension APIs in the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). To create a new tab for example you'd have to look at the [tabs api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) and request the `tabs` [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) in your add-ons `manifest.json`. You can then load an html file packaged with your add-on by specifying the absolute path to it in reference to the `manifest.json` in the url parameter passed to [`tabs.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create).

For discussing add-on development you can write to and follow the [dev-addons](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-addons) mailing list or join the #webextensions channel on [IRC](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IRC).